# Length 0 result error when using case_when() within map2_int()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data set where each observation is a traffic ticket, the license plate of the car that got the ticket, and the date. I want to have a data set where each observation is a period, a license plate, and the number of tickets received for that plate in that period. I have figured out how to do this with for loops, but when I try to do it using map2_int() I run into the problem that, when trying to add in 0s for the periods where a license plate has no tickets using map2_int() and case_when(), it tells me that the output is size 0, but has to be size 1.

Here is a reproducible example of both the code with for loops that works, and the code with map2_int that doesn't work. If the way I'm going about the task itself is fundamentally flawed, let me know, but I'm mainly just trying to better understand how to do stuff without writing lots of for loops.

The code that works:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- 
tibble(
  period = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
  var = c("a","b","c", "a","b","c"), 
  count = c(2,1,50,1,1,1)
  )

new_data <-
  tibble(
  period = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  var = c("a","b","c", "a","b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
  count = rep(0, 9)
)

all_vars <- c("a", "b", "c")

all_periods <- c(1:3)

for (i in all_vars) {
  for(j in all_periods){
    new_data[new_data$period == j & new_data$var == i,]$count <- 
      ifelse(
         i %in% as.vector(filter(data, period == j)$var), 
         filter(data, period == j & var == i)$count,
         0
      ) 
  }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The code that doesn't work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- 
tibble(
  period = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
  var = c("a","b","c", "a","b","c"), 
  count = c(2,1,50,1,1,1)
  )

new_data <-
  tibble(
  period = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  var = c("a","b","c", "a","b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
  count = rep(0, 9)
)



new_data$count <- map2_int(
                    new_data$var, 
                    new_data$period, 
                    \(x, y)
                       case_when(
                         x %in% data[data$period == y,]$var ~
                         data[data$period == y & data$var == x,]$count,
                         .default = 0 
                       )
                  )
#> Error in `map2_int()`:
#> ℹ In index: 6.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Result must be length 1, not 0.
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─purrr::map2_int(...)
#>  2. │ └─purrr:::map2_("integer", .x, .y, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
#>  3. │   ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
#>  4. │   │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  5. │   └─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
#>  6. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  7.   └─purrr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  8.     └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  9.       └─rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: try running the case_when statement for your function at index 6 as suggested by the error: x=var[6], y=period[6]

Answer (score 2):

Did not have a look at what's the issue with `map` but IMHO you could achieve your desired result much easier using a join:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

new_data |>
  select(-count) |>
  left_join(data, by = c("period", "var")) |>
  replace_na(list(count = 0))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   period var   count
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1      1 a         2
#> 2      1 b         1
#> 3      1 c        50
#> 4      2 a         1
#> 5      2 b         1
#> 6      2 c         0
#> 7      3 a         0
#> 8      3 b         0
#> 9      3 c         1
```